# GCD and mod in Coq

Tags: modulo, coq, greatest-common-divisor

I'm stuck at a problem in Coq, would be great if anyone had any tips on how to break the problem down into smaller steps. The lemma is this:

```
Lemma gcd_prime : forall (a b : Z), a > 1 -> b > 1 -> 
  Z.gcd a b = 1 -> Zmod a b <> 0
```

That is, if `a` and `b` are coprime and higher than `1`, `a mod b` is not `0`.

This is where I'm stuck:

```
 p : positive
 p0 : positive
 H : Z.pos p > 1
 H0 : Z.pos p0 > 1
 H1 : Z.gcd (Z.pos p) (Z.pos p0) = 1
  ============================
  Z.pos p mod Z.pos p0 <> 0
```

After doing the intros and induction and removed the obvious cases.

Maybe I must rephrase the `mod` part into `remainder` instead? Or should I replace `H1` with something weaker, like `p <> p0`?

Doing `SearchAbout Zmod.` returns a lot of lemmas, but I'm not sure on how to adapt them.

Regards

Olle

Comment: I find it usually helps, when stuck on a Coq proof, to write out how I would prove this in a traditional prose proof. Can you write that here ? That will help us see which next step you wish to take.

Comment: @jbapple I don't know. I think I need simpler relations between gcd and mod. Or unfold the definitions so it's more explicit.

Comment: In my experience, if I don't know how to do the paper proof, the resulting Coq proof has little value to me. I'd suggest you do the paper proof first. In my prose proof, I would use Bézout's identity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SearchAbout` and `omega` are your friends. Remember you can search things that mention several definitions at once, such as `Z.gcd` and `0`. Here's a solution:

```
Require Import ZArith.

Open Scope Z_scope.

Lemma gcd_prime : forall (a b : Z), a > 1 -> b > 1 ->
  Z.gcd a b = 1 -> Zmod a b <> 0.
Proof.
  intros a b Ha Hb Hgcd Hmod.
  rewrite (Z_div_mod_eq a b), Hmod, Zplus_0_r in Hgcd; try omega.
  rewrite Z.gcd_comm, Z.gcd_mul_diag_l in Hgcd; omega.
Qed.
```

Comment: How did you find all the relevant lemmas for this proof? Except using SearchAbout and such.

Comment: Also, when I run `SearchAbout Z_div_mod_eq`, coq doesn't print anything. No error message either.

Comment: First question: I usually think about some property that might be available as a lemma and useful for my proof, and then try to `SearchAbout` things that mention the definitions involved. E.g. I might want to say "if a mod b = 0, then we know that a = k * b", and then do `SearchAbout Zmod 0.` to see what if finds. Second question: that command causes Coq to look for lemmas that are _about_ `Z_div_mod_eq`, i.e. a lemma about a lemma. This is not an error, but it is not able to find anything, so it doesn't answer. You probably want something like the previous command to get what you want.